# Lock a single Picklist value

Tags: picklist

How can I restrict users from viewing access to a single picklist value? only admin users should be able to see this value.

Comment: Hi Thokozile. What does it mean to you to restrict users from viewing a picklist value? Do you mean that only admins should be able to *choose* that value?

Comment: Yes, correct. only admins should be able to choose that value. thank you

Answer (score 3):

Suppose for the sake of example that the Picklist in question is Opportunity Stage Name and the restricted value is Closed Won. Only selected users (such as system administrators) should be able to choose Closed Won, but users who otherwise have the right to see Opportunities can always see the field value.

I would approach this by creating a **Custom Permission** called "Opportunity - Can Set Closed Won". I'd apply this Custom Permission to the System Administrator profile, and optionally to other users via a Permission Set.

Then I would write a Validation Rule on the Opportunity like so:

```
ISCHANGED(StageName) && ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won") && NOT($Permission.Opp_Can_Set_Closed_Won)
```

This solution is nicely maintainable because you have the freedom to apply the right to choose the picklist value via Profiles or Permission Sets in the future. You can also decide whether you want to allow other edits to Closed Won records (i.e., to fields other than Stage - just remove the `ISCHANGED()` check to prohibit all edits).

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is **Yes**.

You could create a specific record type for the end user and another for the SysAdmin .

So, you can configure the values that only the end user could see. Also, give access for this Record Type for the end users. Work in the same way for SysAdmin. You control the access for each record type in Profile or Permission Set.